# Quiz Multiple choice how to make options non-randomized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a Multiple choice quiz that was made by someone else but he is not available now to help me out. I'm new to coding. I want to have my options in order. Right now when I type in options, options 1 will always be the correct answer, and the code will automatically randomize the options so the correct right won't always be options 1 when my students do the quiz. Can someone help me so that the options will be in the same order as I put them in the code while it can also detect the correct answer? Thank you!

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var questionNumber=0;
var questionBank=new Array();
var stage="#game1";
var stage2=new Object;
var questionLock=false;
var numberOfQuestions;
var score=0;


    $.getJSON('activity.json', function(data) {

    for(i=0;i<data.quizlist.length;i++){ 
        questionBank[i]=new Array;
        questionBank[i][0]=data.quizlist[i].question;
        questionBank[i][1]=data.quizlist[i].option1;
        questionBank[i][2]=data.quizlist[i].option2;
        questionBank[i][3]=data.quizlist[i].option3;
        questionBank[i][4]=data.quizlist[i].option4;
        questionBank[i][5]=data.quizlist[i].option5;
    }
     numberOfQuestions=questionBank.length; 


    scrambleDatabase();
    displayQuestion();
    })//gtjson


fillDB();

 function scrambleDatabase(){
for(i=0;i<60;i++){ 
var rnd1=Math.floor(Math.random()*questionBank.length);
var rnd2=Math.floor(Math.random()*questionBank.length);

var temp=questionBank[rnd1];
questionBank[rnd1]=questionBank[rnd2];
questionBank[rnd2]=temp;

}//i

 }//scdb

function displayQuestion(){
 var rnd=Math.random()*3;
rnd=Math.ceil(rnd);
 var q1;
 var q2;
 var q3;
 var q4;
 var q5;


if(rnd==1){q1=questionBank[questionNumber][1];q2=questionBank[questionNumber][2];q3=questionBank[questionNumber][3];q4=questionBank[questionNumber][4];q5=questionBank[questionNumber][5];}
if(rnd==2){q2=questionBank[questionNumber][1];q3=questionBank[questionNumber][2];q1=questionBank[questionNumber][3];q4=questionBank[questionNumber][4];q5=questionBank[questionNumber][5];}
if(rnd==3){q3=questionBank[questionNumber][1];q4=questionBank[questionNumber][2];q5=questionBank[questionNumber][3];q1=questionBank[questionNumber][4];q2=questionBank[questionNumber][5];}
if(rnd==4){q4=questionBank[questionNumber][1];q5=questionBank[questionNumber][2];q1=questionBank[questionNumber][3];q2=questionBank[questionNumber][4];q3=questionBank[questionNumber][5];}
if(rnd==5){q5=questionBank[questionNumber][1];q1=questionBank[questionNumber][2];q2=questionBank[questionNumber][3];q3=questionBank[questionNumber][4];q4=questionBank[questionNumber][5];}

$(stage).append('<div class="questionText"><img src="play.png"></br>What sound is this?</div><div id="1" class="option">'+q1+'</div><div id="2" class="option">'+q2+'</div><div id="3" class="option">'+q3+'</div><div id="4" class="option">'+q4+'</div><div id="5" class="option">'+q5+'</div>');

$('.option').click(function(){
  if(questionLock==false){questionLock=true;    
  //correct answer
  if(this.id==rnd){
 $(stage).append('<div class="feedback1"><img src="happy.png">CORRECT</div>');
     currentSoundName="sounds/correct.mp3";
    $("#dummy")[0].innerHTML='<audio id="correcttag"     src='+currentSoundName+' autobuffer="autobuffer"></audio>';
   $('#correcttag')[0].play();  
   score++;
   }
     //wrong answer 
      if(this.id!=rnd){
   $(stage).append('<div class="feedback2"><img    src="sad.png">WRONG</div>');
     currentSoundName="sounds/incorrect.mp3";
   $("#dummy")[0].innerHTML='<audio id="correcttag"     src='+currentSoundName+' autobuffer="autobuffer"></audio>';
   $('#correcttag')[0].play();  

 }
    setTimeout(function(){changeQuestion()},1000);
 }})

 currentSoundName="sounds/"+questionBank[questionNumber][0];

  $('.questionText').click(function(){ 
  $("#dummy")[0].innerHTML='<audio id="audiotag" src='+currentSoundName+' autobuffer="autobuffer"></audio>';
$('#audiotag')[0].play();                               


})

}//display question



function changeQuestion(){

    questionNumber++;

if(stage=="#game1"){stage2="#game1";stage="#game2";}
    else{stage2="#game2";stage="#game1";}

if(questionNumber<numberOfQuestions){displayQuestion();}else{displayFinalSlide();}

 $(stage2).animate({"right": "+=800px"},"slow", function() {$(stage2).css('right','-800px');$(stage2).empty();});
 $(stage).animate({"right": "+=800px"},"slow", function() {questionLock=false;});
}//change question




function displayFinalSlide(){

    $(stage).append('<div class="questionText">You have finished the quiz!<br><br>Total questions: '+numberOfQuestions+'<br>Correct answers: '+score+'</div>');

}//display final slide






});//doc ready
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

<title>Quiz</title>
<link href="main.css"rel="stylesheet"type="text/css"/>
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="controller.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="topbar">Quiz</div>
<div class="spacer"></div>

<div id="navContent">

<div id="game1"></div>
<div id="game2"></div>
</div>


<span id="dummy"></span>

</body>
</html>
```

My Question data bank is a json file like this:
json:

```
{"quizlist":[

{
"question":"ba.mp3",
"option1":"a",
"option2":"b",
"option3":"c",
"option4":"d",
"option5":"e"
}
```

Comment: if you want to stop the answers in options to be randomized then just don't call the **scrambleDatabase** function by removing/commenting the calling statement.

Answer (score 0):

I would make the following edits.

First edit your Question data bank json file to include an extra field for the correct answer (use the number of the answer):

```
{"quizlist":[

{
"question":"ba.mp3",
"answer":2,
"option1":"a",
"option2":"b",
"option3":"c",
"option4":"d",
"option5":"e"
}
```

Then read this answer into your data bank array:

```
questionBank[i][0]=data.quizlist[i].question;
questionBank[i][1]=data.quizlist[i].option1;
questionBank[i][2]=data.quizlist[i].option2;
questionBank[i][3]=data.quizlist[i].option3;
questionBank[i][4]=data.quizlist[i].option4;
questionBank[i][5]=data.quizlist[i].option5;
questionBank[i][6]=data.quizlist[i].answer;
```

then remove the section that randomizes teh answers and just read the answers into the variables in your order and store the correct answer in rnd (i would rename this variable):

```
function displayQuestion(){

var q1 = questionBank[questionNumber][1];
var q2 = questionBank[questionNumber][2];
var q3 = questionBank[questionNumber][3];
var q4 = questionBank[questionNumber][4];
var q5 = questionBank[questionNumber][5];
var rnd = questionBank[questionNumber][6];

$(stage).append('<div class="questionText"><img src="play.png"></br>What sound is this?</div><div id="1" class="option">'+q1+'</div><div id="2" class="option">'+q2+'</div><div id="3" class="option">'+q3+'</div><div id="4" class="option">'+q4+'</div><div id="5" class="option">'+q5+'</div>');
```

And that should do it

EDIT: This wouldnt be my prefered way of producing a multi choice quiz but it should give you what you want with minimal edits to your existing code.

Comment: sorry I forgot to say, I also would like my question to be random but not the options. So if I delete the randomizer in my code then the questions will be in order. Is there anyway to just randomize the options? Thank you.

Comment: @Shannon Sorry If my anwser wasnt the clearest. It will still randomize the questions i just meant remove the bit that randomizes the anwers. I have edited the answer to hopfully be more clear.